# Is there a way to do Stencil Shadows in Blender?

Tags: mesh, shaders, shadows

Is There a way to do Stencil Shadows (Stencil buffer) in blender ? or at least a way to cast texture in a shape of seperate mesh

Comment: Read up on Material Cryptomattes. Is that what you are after? @Loko

Comment: i need something closer to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume from what i know this was used in mario games

Comment: What is the purpose of such thing for you in blender ? Do you have some visual expectations or data format ... if you need just sharp shadows disable all light bounces and set Point light Size to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Diffuse Colour and Shadow passes and manipulate them in the Compositor. In my case, I used the Eevee renderer with a 0 radius light and Soft Shadows turned off. I used the Exposure node in the compositor with the Shadow pass as the exposure factor.

The following GIF was rendered once, combining different render passes in the Compositor.
From top to bottom :

- Diffuse Colour and Shadow pass
- Shadow pass
- Diffuse Colour

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show me a blend file of this and also is this only work on pre rendered stuff ?

Comment: Edited answer with blend file @Loko . And yeah, compositing has to be rendered and cannot be viewed in the viewport directly.